# How to avoid exception by mapping string to number in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have some HTML page and on this page I will provide the possibility for free text.

For example, it is possible to write in `textbox` either: `10` or `10 apples`.
In a case of writing `10 apples` I got `NumberFormatException` which is correct, but for me will be good to extract only number automatically without javascript writing.

Is it possible to map string from HTML page to the number in my java entity? May be with some annotation or somehow else?

Comment: why do you allow text if you dont want it?

Comment: This is the requirement for the HTML page.

Comment: you have to do it by your own like described in the answer or create an own annotation where you write your code onces.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
final String stripped = textbox.getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

This takes the contents of the text field and strips out any characters that aren't digits.  If you need to deal with floating point or negative numbers, it can be done, but becomes more complicated.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using the annotations?

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt it.